# Quick-release _below_ the head

Tags: video, tripod-heads, quick-release

What would you recommend for quickly changing and moving heads from tripod to monopod, slider, etc.

Would a cheap Arca Swiss copy or a 200PL be a good option?

To be used with Mirrorless and DSLR with light lenses, both for photography and video purposes.

Comment: What do you have on top of the heads?

Comment: @MikeSowsun All my heads have QR plates on the bottom, because I change between using ballheads, geared heads, and gimbal heads on my heavy duty tripod, which has a QR clamp on top. This allows me to select the right head, depending on what I'm shooting.

Comment: I understand now, but I have never seen anyone use multiple heads on one tripod. You might be the only person doing this. What is wrong the the quick release plates you are using now?

Comment: @scottbb This is, precisely, what I want to do. That's why I'm asking what type of QR clamp are you using and whether you have a good experience with it.

Comment: @MikeSowsun Good fluid heads are expensive. I have an old, heavy, tripod I use at home and a new, no so good but much lighter I use when going out. I want to share the same head with both. I also have a simple ball head I prefer for photography. That's why the quick changing heads would be useful.

Comment: @scottbb On top of the heads I use an old DSLR (non video capable) and a mid range video camera, and, sometimes, (cough, cough) my smartphone.

Comment: I'm sorry, when I asked what you have on top of the heads, I assumed you were using some sort of QR clamp on top, and plates mounted to the bottom of your camera(s). The point of my question was that if you had a robust QR system on top of the heads, the same system between the heads and tripod makes sense.

Comment: What is a PL200? It's not a unique part name in the industry.

Comment: @scottbb The 200PL family of plates is part of the most common Manfrotto QR system. The 200PL-14 is the most common plate within the 200PL series. 200PL plates are used with RC2 receivers.

Comment: @MichaelC I figured, but I'm the wording "PL200" vs. "200PL", lots of generic 200mm plates pop up at Amazon, eBay, etc., as well as some non 200PL products trying to capitalize on the name confusion. I was hoping OP might be more specific about what they meant when I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Kirk and RRS both offer solutions for this.

IMO the Kirk offerings are a bit more flexible and cost effective... at this moment the large clamp is $120/plates are $29, and the small clamp is $100/plates $24. I suspect the small clamp/plates would likely suit your needs.

The RRS clamp (one size only) is currently $130/plates $55. The RRS system uses a lever clamp as opposed to the screw clamp of the Kirk.

There have been other solutions on the market over the years, but I'm not aware of any at the moment. You could DIY easily enough using a lever release type clamp and a standard plate... the clamp would need to have 3/8-16 threads (many do) and the plate would have to be modified to use a 3/8-16 screw. A screw type clamp could also be used, but finding one large enough and with a long enough clamping knob to clear the base could be more problematic.